# Set string of a variable from JTable row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm trying to get the string in one of my rows in my table and put it in my variable a. How can I do that? Here's my code:

```
int row = tb_add.getSelectedRow();
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)tb_add.getModel();

String a;
a.setText(model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());
```

I'm getting a redline error at setText. I think it's only for objects? How about in a string variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API called as `setText(String)` in String class. you can use

```
String a=model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
```

Comment: @user2942600: Accept the answer so that question will be closed

Answer (score 0):

```
String a  = (String)model.getValueAt(row, 1);
```

should do it for you. Because values in table model are instances of `java.lang.Object`. It happens to be a string in your case. If you would like to be more careful in what you are doing, you can do it as below.

```
Object o = model.getValueAt(row, 1);
  String a = null
  if (o instanceof String) {
     a =  (String) o;
  }
```

Sometimes just calling `toString()` method may not really an apt way, as it may return plain `toString` implementation from `Object` class even if the value of `JTable`'s column is not of type `java.lang.String`, but any `JComponent` or `object` embedded in the table column.

Note:

a.setText must throw an compilation error for you as there is no such method defined in `java.lang.String`

Answer (score 0):

As `a` is a String variable you should do something like this:

```
String a = model.getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
```